# How to send several requests in one time

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

well guys I am going to do a project which send work order in c# web service and receive response ,but I need help cause I want to take several data then send it to the web service but I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

To give an idea, you can use Parallel.ForEach for performing multiple web service calls at a time. I don't really know what do you want to pass but this should be a good start.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

Parallel.ForEach(callParameters, (callParam) => 
{
   // Web Service Calls
});
```